# problem with for loop in threading and using webclient

Tags: multithreading, for-loop

I have a csv file. In column 41 found urls separated with “;”. I made a program, which iterate through each row, then separate cell[41] with “;” to array, then iterate through this array and download each url to a file jpg. Because it is a big data, I do it with thread. My problem is, the for loop does not begin with 1, it begins with 82 or 84 und jumps over many rows. Can you please help me?

The code:
Starting the thread:

```
private void BtnDownloadPictures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dstFile = "newFile.csv";
        lblStatus.Text = "Starting...";
        ThreadStart threadStart = dp;
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
        thread.Start();
    }
private void dp()
    {
        // calculating how many rows there is in csv file


        var file = new StreamReader(dstFile).ReadToEnd(); 
        var lines = file.Split(new char[] { '\n' });           
        var count = lines.Length;
        label3.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text = "Number of rows : " + count.ToString());
        progressBar1.SafeInvoke(d => d.Maximum = 100);
        progressBar1.SafeInvoke(d => d.Minimum = 0);

// here begins the for loop. It should start with 1. But that doesn’t happen

        for (var i = 1; i < count - 1; i++)
        {
            var cells = lines[i].Split(',');
            var urls = cells[41].Split(';');
            for (var j = 0; j < urls.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text += i.ToString() + ": " + urls[j] + Environment.NewLine);
                if (urls[j].StartsWith("http"))
                {
                    lblStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text = "Downloading  picture number " + j.ToString() + " from row " + i.ToString());
                    downloadPics(urls[j]);
                }

            }
            var p = (int)Math.Round((double)(100 * i) / count);
            progressBar1.SafeInvoke(d =>
            {
                d.Value = p;
                d.Refresh();
                d.CreateGraphics().DrawString(p.ToString() + "%",
            new Font("Arial", (float)8.25, FontStyle.Regular),
            Brushes.Black,
            new PointF(d.Width / 2 - 10, d.Height / 2 - 7));
            });
        }
        txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text += "Mission finisched successfully" + Environment.NewLine);
        txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.SelectionStart = d.Text.Length);
        txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.SelectionLength = 0);
    }

  private void downloadPics(string url)
    {


        try
        {
            string cd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\downloaded pictures";
            string fn = cd + @"\" + url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            if (!Directory.Exists(cd))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(cd);
            }
            if (!File.Exists(fn))
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClientWithTimeout();
                wc.DownloadFile(url, cd + @"\" + url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1));
                txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text += "Added successfully! " + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text += "File already exists " + Environment.NewLine);
            }



        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            // add some kind of error processing
            txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text += we.Message + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        finally
        {
            txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.SelectionStart = d.Text.Length);
            txtStatus.SafeInvoke(d => d.SelectionLength = 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Cell[41] not always includes a url. that means error in csv file. Sorry I want to delete this question